# Why can't I solve $\int \sin^3(x)dx$ directly using u-substitution without trig identities?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I saw that the standard solution to the problem

$\int \sin^3(x)dx$

involves first using trig identities and then u-substitution. I am not understanding why it is wrong to use directly u-substitution, such as:

$u=\sin x$

$du=\cos x  dx$

$\frac{1}{\cos x}\int \sin^3(x)\cdot \cos x dx =\frac{1}{\cos x} \int u^3du= \frac{\sin^4(x)}{4\cos x}$

Comment: You can't let $1/\cos(x)$ pass through the integral; it depends on $x$. Surely you wouldn't say $\int x\,dx = x \int dx = x^2+C$ - same idea.

Comment: Or letting $u=x^2$ when integrating $x^2\,dx,$ you'd get $$\frac1{2x}\int u\,du=\frac1{2x}\cdot \frac{u^2}2=\frac{x^3}4.$$

Comment: Thank you both! Your examples made the point clear as water :)